# How to save channel19.msdn video on my pc?

Tags: windows

What is the easiest free way to do so ?

I want to save this one:
http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx/

Can't see any menu to do so (either on Firefox or IE7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) then it's very easy and very free: Just click one of the "Media Downloads" links:

[image: Media Downloads drop-down on Channel 9]

Comment: Hi thanks but I can't see any such menu for this one at least:
http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx/

Comment: I can see it using Google Chrome. You have to scroll down past all the text (sample code) on the right column to see it.

Comment: Oh my you're right and I'm blind ;)